# ORACLE SQL - How to check whether a time falls within a particular range?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a column 'DateTime' that displays the Date and Time in 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' format.
I need to display only the rows that has time in a particular range(2AM - 6AM) regardless of the particular date.
I have a code that only displays the time range(2AM - 6AM) for the particular day. I need to display the rows that falls in the past 7 days with the time range 2AM-6AM.

```
SELECT *
    FROM <table_name >
   WHERE DateTime BETWEEN TO_DATE (
                                    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                 || ' '
                                 || '02:00:00',
                                 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                          AND TO_DATE (
                                    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                 || ' '
                                 || '06:00:00',
                                 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: The `DATE` data type does not have a format - it is stored internally as [7-bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6848/the-format-of-a-date) (2 for year and 1 each for month, day, hour, minute and seconds). It is only when the user interface (e.g. SQL/Plus, SQL developer, TOAD, Java, Python, etc) processes it that it is given a format - the default format is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and this can be [changed by individual users](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6850/setting-the-default-date-format-model) in their sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You need two conditions for that: one for the hour being between `02` and `05`, and one for the day being in the last seven days:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    <table_name>
WHERE   to_char(DateTime, 'HH') BETWEEN '02' and '05' AND
        DateTime BETWEEN SYSDATE - 7 AND SYSDATE
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Oracle dates support arithmetic operations, so you don't need to do string comparisons to implement this sort of logic. Plus, using date arithmetic allows the optimiser to use indexes (if any) more efficiently.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp you're right, thanks! I improved my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TO_CHAR( DateTime, 'HH24MMSS' ) BETWEEN '020000' AND '060000'
AND    DateTime >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY
AND    DateTime <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  DateTime BETWEEN TRUNC( DateTime ) + INTERVAL '2' HOUR
                    AND TRUNC( DateTime ) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
AND    DateTime >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY
AND    DateTime <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think the easiest way *is* string comparison:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(DateTime, 12, 2) BETWEEN '02' and '05'
```

Note:  Between is inclusive so this should get everything up to 05:59:59.

Comment: This relies on implicit conversion of a date to a string. This depends heavily on the value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as Oracle will use this as the default format mask when converting the date (in the absence of an explicit format mask). So if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is changed to `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM:SS` then this will fail without changing the query.

Comment: @MT0 . . . Absolutely not.  Given the statement "There is a column 'DateTime' that displays the Date and Time in 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' ", my assumption is that the column is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM <table_name >
   WHERE DateTime BETWEEN TO_DATE (
                                    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE)-7, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                 || ' '
                                 || '02:00:00',
                                 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                          AND TO_DATE (
                                    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                                 || ' '
                                 || '06:00:00',
                                 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where to_char(datetime,'HH24') 
between '2' and '6' and to_char(datetime,'dd-mon-yy') 
between to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy')  and to_char(sysdate-7,'dd-mon-yy');
```